# C# Getting the attribute of an html element

Tags: c#

I have this block of code

```
<button value="1" class="_42ft _4jy0 _n6m _4jy3 _517h _51sy" data-hover="tooltip" aria-label="Start a video call with Tsiato" type="submit" id="js_rk"><i class="_e0b img sp_qk8sNUxukfD sx_4816f8"></i></button>
```

And I am trying to access that "aria-label" to see if it contains the word "Start"...

using this code

```
try 
{ 
    HtmlElementCollection buttons = pinger.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");
    foreach (HtmlElement curElement in buttons)
    {
        if (curElement.GetAttribute("classname").ToString() == "_42ft _4jy0 _n6m _4jy3 _517h _51sy")
        {
            if (curElement.GetAttribute("aria-label").ToString().Contains("Start a video call"))
            {
                label5.Text = "online";
            }
        }
    }
} catch (NullReferenceException b) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());
}
```

I can find the class but I can't get the attribute "aria-label" to see if it contains any "Start" text...
Can you tell me whats wrong here ? :\

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Nullreferenceexception

Comment: If it's using a DOM object somewhere, it might be required to use 'ariaLabel'? Just a guess.

Comment: Did you solved this problem?

Answer (score 1):

1. Your **class=** attribute has name "class", not "classname".
2. If your method GetAttribute(string) can return null, you should always check returned value.

   ```
   if (curElement.GetAttribute("classname") == "_42ft _4jy0 _n6m _4jy3 _517h _51sy" 
   && (curElement.GetAttribute("aria-label") ?? "").Contains("Start a video call"))
   {
       label5.Text = "online";
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

So if there is a button that does not contain aria-label as an attribute, you will get the nullreference exception because you are using the Contains() Method on null.

So try this:

```
        String ariaLabel = curElement.GetAttribute("aria-label");
        if (ariaLabel != null && ariaLabel.Length != 0)
        {
            if(ariaLabel.Contains("Start a video call"))
            {
               // do your stuff
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try this -

```
var p = "<button value='1' class='_42ft _4jy0 _n6m _4jy3 _517h _51sy' data-hover='tooltip' aria-label='Start a video call with Tsiato' type='submit' id='js_rk'><i class='_e0b img sp_qk8sNUxukfD sx_4816f8'></i></button>";
var k = new XmlDocument();
k.Load(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(p.ToCharArray())));
Console.WriteLine(k.GetElementsByTagName("button")[0].Attributes["aria-label"].Value);
```